# supports SSL (https) JSON-RPC connections

Tags: go-ethereum

Does ethereum node supports SSL (https) JSON-RPC connections like in Bitcoin? is there any work on control access over ethereum rpc nodes?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go-ethereum(geth) does not.  I can't speak for other clients.  Your best bet is to setup nginx as a reverse proxy and have nginx handle the SSL/TLS.  That's what I'm doing, and it works pretty well.

This also does not take into any other security issues, so you really should only limit the calls to read-only(i.e. no `personal` API availability).

Comment: Could you share your nginx config or references? I don't know how to set up the reverse proxy.

Comment: I'm trying this https://tokenmarket.net/blog/protecting-ethereum-json-rpc-api-with-password/

Comment: @zono Yep, that's pretty much it.